# Any way to add support for Haitian Creole in B2C Localization

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Have followed the guidance at [Language customization in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) to add localization for Azure AD B2C Custom Policy. No problems adding support for Spanish, Russian, etc. Our front end application also supports Haitian Creole that has a language code of `ht` but attempting to use this as a supported language in Azure AD B2C just fails.

[Supported Languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#supported-languages) lists 36 supported languages but Haitian Creole is not in that list.

Is anyone aware of a way to support this language for localization with B2C Custom Policy?

Answer (score 0):

Haitian Creole is not an Azure AD B2C supported language. You can let the product team know about your interest [posting an idea in the Azure AD feedback forums.](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/post/)